# Evaluate $\lim_{n\to \infty} \left( \sum_{r=0}^n \frac {2^r}{5^{2^r}+1}\right) $

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, limits, summation

> Evaluate $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left( \sum_{r=0}^n \frac {2^r}{5^{2^r}+1}\right) $$

I tried to create some infinite GP within the summation,  some algebraic manipulations like adding the first and last terms of the summation to find any series popping out of it and also tried writing it in the exponential form like $5^{2^r}=e^{2^r\ln 5}$ and also tried to do some power series thing. I also tried to find any method using integrals and Riemann sums but couldn't do so.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you think this series should have a nice evaluation? An extremely accurate evaluation will come from just the first few terms, since this series converges very, very rapidly.

Comment: Euler-Maclaurin may be the way

Comment: @PierpaoloVivo I don't see how this question relates to it

Comment: Numerically, it "seems to go" to $\displaystyle\color{red}{1 \over 4}$.

Comment: @FelixMarin Yeah I got to know about that from Wolfy but I want an algebraic hint or some kind method to do it by hand by proper means

Comment: @Felix Marin I want a method that can be done by hand by proper methods

Comment: I know that. However, a 'numerical check' is always useful. Specially when the problem at hand isn't trivial.

Comment: @FelixMarin By the way did you get any idea how to answer this question. Now I have tried nearly 3 hours for this question with no success

Answer (score 18, accepted):

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left( \sum_{r=0}^n \frac {2^r}{5^{2^r}+1}\right) $$
$$=\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{r=0}^n\left( \frac {2^r}{5^{2^r}+1}\cdot \frac {5^{2^r}-1}{5^{2^r}-1}\right) $$
$$=\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{r=0}^n \left(\frac {2^r((5^{2^r}+1)-2)}{5^{2^{r+1}}-1}\right) $$
$$=\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{r=0}^n \left( \frac {2^r}{5^{2^r}-1} -\frac {2^{r+1}}{5^{2^{r+1}}-1}\right)$$
$$=\frac {1}{5-1}=\frac 14$$

Note: In fact using this method it can be proved that for any natural number $a$ (except of course $a=1$) $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(\sum_{r=0}^n \frac {2^r}{a^{2^r}+1}\right) =\frac {1}{a-1}$$

Comment: +1. Very clever.

Comment: @Felix Marin Thanks a lot

Comment: Good job, +1) .

Comment: Telescoping sums are so nice. (+1)

Comment: @xpaul Thanks...

Comment: @Kirk Fox Thanks...

Answer (score 6):

The key is to understand that if $|x|<1$ then $$(1+x)(1+x^2)(1+x^4)\dots(1+x^{2^n})\dots=\frac{1}{1-x}$$ Now taking logs and differentiating it we get $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{2^nx^{2^n-1}}{1+x^{2^n}}=\frac{1}{1-x}$$ Putting $x=1/t,|t|>1$ we get $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{2^n}{1+t^{2^n}}=\frac{1}{t-1}$$ Putting $t=5$ we get the desired limit in question.