# Evaluate the value of series

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

$$\sum^\infty_{k=0 }\frac{2^k}{5^{2^k}+1}$$

The hint is expanding it to double series.

So, $$\frac{2^k}{5^{2^k}+1}=\frac{2^k}{5^{2^k}}\frac{1}{1+5^{-2^k}}=\frac{2^k}{5^{2^k}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n5^{-n2^k}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{2^k}{5^{2^k(n+1)}}$$

Thus $$\sum^\infty_{k=0 }\frac{2^k}{5^{2^k}+1}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{2^k}{5^{2^k(n+1)}}$$

Since $$\sum^\infty_{k=0 }\frac{2^k}{5^{2^k}+1}\lt \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{2^k}{5^k}=\frac{5}{3}$$

It is always increasing and has an upper bond. So it converges.

Therefore the order of the double series is exchangeable. But what to do next?

[image]

Comment: Where did this question originate? Was the hint to use double series given there?

Comment: PUMaC 2017 division A question. The solution used double series to solve. I understand how to solve it now but I am still looking for how to use double series to solve it. @robjohn

Comment: You have the solution there which uses double series. What part is troubling?

Comment: The part with $$\sum_{N=1}^\infty \frac{1}{5^N}$$ I don't know where does it from. How do they rearrange that?

Comment: I have added an analysis of the solution provided to my answer.

Comment: Duplicate of [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2741632).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Telescopic Solution**

Notice that
$$
\frac{2^k}{5^{2^k}-1}-\frac{2^k}{5^{2^k}+1}=\frac{2^{k+1}}{5^{2^{k+1}}-1}
$$
Therefore, we get a telescoping series:
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{2^k}{5^{2^k}+1}
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(\frac{2^k}{5^{2^k}-1}-\frac{2^{k+1}}{5^{2^{k+1}}-1}\right)\\[6pt]
&=\frac14
\end{align}
$$

---

**Analysis of the Solution Provided**

> Let $\Xi=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{2^k}{5^{2^k}+1}$. Note that
>   $$
> \frac{2^k}{5^{2^k}+1}=\frac{2^k}{5^{2^k}}\frac1{1+5^{-2^k}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{2^k}{5^{2^k(n+1)}}.\tag1
> $$

$(1)$ uses the sum of a geometric series

> Therefore, we have
>   $$
> \Xi=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{2^k}{5^{2^k(n+1)}}
> =\sum_{N=1}^\infty\frac1{5^N}\sum_{N=(n+1)2^k}(-1)^n2^k.\tag2
> $$

In $(2)$, we have collected all the terms with a given power of $5$ in the denominator. Now comes the part that seems to be what is causing the difficulty:

> Given any $N\in\mathbb{N}$, let $N=a2^m$ where $a$ and $m$ are non-negative integers and $a$ is odd. Then, for fixed $N$, we have
>   $$
> \sum_{N=(n+1)2^k}(-1)^n2^k=\sum_{k=0}^m(-1)^{a2^{m-k}-1}2^k
> =2^m-\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}2^k=1.\tag3
> $$

In other words, for any positive $N\in\mathbb{N}$, we can uniquely factor $N=a2^m$ where $a$ is odd. In $(2)$, we want to use all $n$ and $k$ so that $N=a2^m=(n+1)2^k$. For $0\le k\le m$, we have $n+1=a2^{m-k}$. Since $a$ is odd, $n$ is even for $k=m$ and odd for all $k\lt m$. Therefore,
$$
\sum_{N=(n+1)2^k}(-1)^n2^k=2^m-2^{m-1}-2^{m-2}-\cdots-1=1\tag4
$$
Plugging $(4)$ into $(2)$ yields

> Therefore,
>   $$
> \Xi=\sum_{N=1}^\infty\frac1{5^N}=\frac14.\tag5
> $$

Comment: Note that by this method, for $x\gt1$, $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{2^k}{x^{2^k}+1}=\frac1{x-1}$$