# Find the sum of $\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{2^n}{1+7^{2^n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

My attempt:
$\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{2^n}{1+7^{2^n}}=\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{1}\frac{2^n}{1+7^{2^n}}+\sum\limits_{1}^{\infty}\frac{2^n}{1+7^{2^n}}+\frac 18\\
=\sum\limits_{1}^{\infty}\frac1{2^n(1+7^{1/2^n})}+\sum\limits_{1}^{\infty}\frac{2^n}{1+7^{2^n}}+\frac 18\\
=\frac 18+\sum\limits_{1}^{\infty}\frac{2^n}{1+7^{2^n}}+\frac1{2^n(1+7^{1/2^n})}
\\$
I am stuck here, is my approach correct and leads to the desired result? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here is a similar problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3281454/42969.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it. How can we evaluate the other sum from $-\infty$ to 0?

Answer (score 3):

You can write this as a telescoping sum.  Note that
$$
\frac{2^n}{7^{2^n}-1} - \frac{2^n}{7^{2^n}+1}=\frac{2^n(7^{2^n}+1)-2^n(7^{2^n}-1)}{7^{2^{n+1}}-1}=\frac{2^{n+1}}{7^{2^{n+1}}-1}.
$$
So
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{2^{n}}{7^{2^n}+1} &=& \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\frac{2^n}{7^{2^n}-1} - \frac{2^{n+1}}{7^{2^{n+1}}-1}\right) \\ &=& \lim_{n\rightarrow-\infty}\frac{2^n}{7^{2^n}-1} - \lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{2^n}{7^{2^n}-1}
\\ &=& \lim_{n\rightarrow-\infty}\frac{2^n}{{2^n}\log 7+o(2^n)} \\ &=&\frac{1}{\log 7}.
\end{eqnarray}
$$